# Add data to Diesel results when user is logged in without using N+1 queries

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I have a movie database where users can mark movies as watched and favorite using the following models:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Identifiable, Queryable, Associations)]
#[table_name = "movies"]
struct Movie {
    id: 32
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Identifiable, Queryable, Associations)]
#[table_name = "users"]
struct User {
    id: 32
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Identifiable, Queryable, Associations)]
#[table_name = "favorite_movies"]
struct FavoriteMovie {
    movie_id: i32,
    user_id: i32,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Identifiable, Queryable, Associations)]
#[table_name = "watched_movies"]
struct WatchedMovie {
    movie_id: i32,
    user_id: i32,
    date: DateTime,
}
```

How would I handle the case where I want to list the 100 latest movies added to the database and also include user data for each movie if a user is logged in while also avoiding the N+1 query problem?

I'm thinking I could add another struct for the `movies` table where I also include optional user data but I'm not sure how I would use it together with the Diesel ORM.

```rust
struct UserData {
   favorite: bool,
   watched: Option<DateTime>,
}

struct UserMovie {
   id: i32,
   user_data: Option<UserData>,
}
```

Comment: I do currently not have the time to type out a full answer, but you've seen the documentation of the [`diesel::associations` API](http://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/associations/index.html)?

Comment: @weiznich I saw this comment after creating my own solution described below. I will have to look into this too and see how they compare.

Comment: @weiznich How would you use `associations` (specifically `belonging_to`) to get results similar to what I've described in my answer where I've used `left_join`? Can I with `associations` get watched movies as `Option<WatchedMovie>` (as I do with `left_join`) instead of lists as described in the API docs?

Comment: Using `left_join` is the right answer for this use case. Maybe I should have looked at the question a bit more in depth…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`left_join`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.4/diesel/query_dsl/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.left_join):

```rust
struct UserMovie {
    movie: Movie,
    favorite_movie: Option<FavoriteMovie>,
    watched_movie: Option<WatchedMovie>,
}

let conn = get_db_connection();
let user_movies: Vec<UserMovie> = movies::table
    .left_join(
        favorite_movies::table.on(favorite_movies::movie_id
            .eq(movies::id)
            .and(favorite_movies::user_id.eq(user_id))),
    )
    .left_join(
        watched_movies::table.on(watched_movies::movie_id
            .eq(movies::id)
            .and(watched_movies::user_id.eq(user_id))),
    )
    .load(conn)?
    .into_iter()
    .map(
        |(movie, favorite_movie, watched_movie): (Movie, Option<FavoriteMovie>, Option<WatchedMovie>)| UserMovie {
            movie,
            favorite_movie,
            watched_movie,
        }
    )
    .collect()
```